# Read xml with dynamic rows and attributes in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have below typed xml

```
 <root>
    <row1 invoice_number="WEDRT" vendor="Telekm" amount="233" status="1" created_date="42590" />
    <row2 invoice_number="MSFDRT" vendor="ARS" amount="344" status="1" created_date="42955" />
</root>
```

This xml is generated dynamically. By dynamic I mean at the time of writing the sql code to parse it I don't know how many rows and attributes would be there. 
There could be as many rows as 100,000 and as many attributes as user wants. I won't even know the name of the attributes.

Is it possible to put it in a temp table by producing following type of result out of this xml?

```
Invoice_number     Vendor     amount   status    created_Date
WEDRT              TELEKOM     233       1        42590
MSFDRT             ARS         344       1        42955
```

I have tried the following

```
    DECLARE
    @xml    XML,
    @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = '
<root>
<row1 invoice_number="WEDRT" vendor="Telekm" amount="233" status="1" created_date="42590" />
<row2 invoice_number="MSFDRT" vendor="ARS" amount="344" status="1" created_date="42955" />
</root>
'
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @COUNT INT, @COUNTER INT, @TQUERY   VARCHAR(2000), @SELECT  VARCHAR(MAX), @VALUES   VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE
        FROM(
        SELECT  
            CAST(x.v.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(100)) As AttributeName,
            v.value('.' , 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Value
            FROM @XML.nodes('//@*') x(v)
            ) A

        SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE 

        DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
END
```

It gives me result like below table for 2 rows in xml

```
AttributeName     Value
invoice_number    WEDRT
vendor            Telekom
amount            233
status            1
created_Date      42590
invoice_number    MSFDRT
vendor            ARS
amount            344
status            1
created_Date      42955
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read"? What do you need from it in the end, in which form?

Comment: @RogerWolf: Sorry, I just updated the expected result.

Comment: You have a nice working solution, you should add row_number to your output, or some identity to ech invoice and then just PIVOT

Comment: @gofr1: Pivoting is fine but as you can see the attribute names are getting repeated after 5 rows. That's why i guess i can't pivot.

Comment: I add solution with dynamic pivoting, hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your query, hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @xml    XML,
        @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = '
<root>
<row1 invoice_number="WEDRT" vendor="Telekm" amount="233" status="1" created_date="42590" />
<row2 invoice_number="MSFDRT" vendor="ARS" amount="344" status="1" created_date="42955" />
</root>
'
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @COUNT INT, @COUNTER INT, @TQUERY   VARCHAR(2000), @SELECT  VARCHAR(MAX), @VALUES   VARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE
        FROM(
            SELECT  CAST(x.v.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(100)) As AttributeName,
                    x.v.value('.' , 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Value],
                    CAST(x.v.query('local-name(..)') AS VARCHAR(100)) As RowNumber
            FROM @XML.nodes('//*//@*') x(v)
        ) A

        DECLARE @t TABLE (AttributeName nvarchar(max), r int)
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
                @col nvarchar(max)

        INSERT INTO @t
        SELECT DISTINCT AttributeName,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowNumber ORDER BY RowNumber) as r
        FROM #TEMPTABLE 

        SELECT @col = (
            SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(AttributeName)
            FROM @t
            ORDER BY r
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )


        SELECT @sql = N'
        SELECT *
        FROM #TEMPTABLE t
        PIVOT (
            MAX([Value]) FOR AttributeName IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
        ) as pvt'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql

        DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
END
```

Output:

```
RowNumber   invoice_number  vendor  amount  status  created_date
row1        WEDRT           Telekm  233     1       42590
row2        MSFDRT          ARS     344     1       42955
```

The main idea is to dynamically pivot your results. To get rid of `RowNumber` column you can use `SELECT '+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+'` instead of `'SELECT *` part

Comment: Beauty, this is just awesome. Thanks a lot. Is there a possible way to remove rownumber from the last selection?

Comment: Of course you can! I add this to my answer, see the very end of it.

Comment: I just did the same. Thanks again. I have got to use temporary tables instead of table variables because the data in the xml string gonna be huge.

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track. Only change you need is to select all elements instead of all attributes:

```
declare @x xml = '<root>
  <row1 invoice_number="WEDRT" vendor="Telekm" amount="233" status="1" created_date="42590" />
  <row2 invoice_number="MSFDRT" vendor="ARS" amount="344" status="1" created_date="42955" />
</root>';

select t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as [NodeName],
    t.c.value('./@invoice_number', 'varchar(50)') as [InvoiceNumber],
    t.c.value('./@vendor', 'varchar(50)') as [Vender],
    t.c.value('./@amount', 'money') as [Amount],
    t.c.value('./@status', 'int') as [Status],
    t.c.value('./@created_date', 'int') as [CreatedDate]
from @x.nodes('/root[1]/*') t(c);
```

I have added the node name as the first column, in case you might need it. Remove it from the query if you don't.

Comment: Thanks but at run time I don't know the name of the columns so I can't hard code as invoice-number, vendor etc.